# How do I determine the number of rows in the last page of an ASP:GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created a class that inherits the System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.  We shall call this... GridViewX!

Anyway, I would like to be able to write a method for it that:
1. Sets a custom boolean property, isLastPage, on page switch.  At the same, time,
2. Sets a custom int property, unmodifiedRowCount that stores the number of records(rows) on the last page.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the pageSize and count the rows of your datasource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Records on last page could be calculated as

```
int lastPageRecords = TotalRecords % PageSize;
```